# Session issue with Quickblox Chat

Tags: android, quickblox

While using **Quickblox** chat, How do i destroy the session when i close the app? so that when i start the app next time it should be able to login in to chat.

What i have tried is calling the **deleteSession** on **onDestroy** of my MainActivity, but it doesnt seems to help.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    QBUsers.signOut(new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.v("SESSION","Session logout");
            ChatService.getInstance().removeConnectionListener(chatConnectionListener);
            QBAuth.deleteSession(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.v("SESSION","Session destroyed");

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.v("SESSION","Session destroyed 2");
                    //i get success here, when i onDestroy is called

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> list) {
                    Log.v("SESSION",list.toString());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List errors) {
            Log.v("SESSIONERROR",errors.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

**Situation:**

When i start the app, it gets the Quickblox session and logs in to the chat.
but if i close the app. next time when i start the app, it gets the **Quickblox** session and gets stuck there.

I need to kill the app from task manager and start the app to login.

**SDK response when i make a fresh start**

```
01-23 23:04:07.017 21733-21733/? D/ChatService: Initialise QBChatService
01-23 23:04:07.027 21733-21733/? D/QBASDK: =========================================================
                                           === REQUEST ==== 66f6e80c-9319-48c6-8d55-374d83c715e2 ===
                                           REQUEST
                                               POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
                                           HEADERS
                                               QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                               QB-SDK=Android 2.3.3
                                           PARAMETERS
                                               application_id=xxxx
                                               auth_key=U48ZQsXad2OcBNa
                                               nonce=-855163362
                                               timestamp=1453570447
                                               user[login]=egun1234
                                               user[password]=egun1234
                                               signature=f3edc13692c8ad3d4aae90717be7c05890ea4780
                                           INLINE
                                               POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=xxxxx&auth_key=U48ZQsXad2OcBNa&nonce=-855163362&timestamp=1453570447&user[login]=egun1234&user[password]=egun1234&signature=f3edc13692c8ad3d4aae90717be7c05890ea4780
01-23 23:04:12.047 21733-21733/? D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
                                           *** RESPONSE *** 66f6e80c-9319-48c6-8d55-374d83c715e2 ***
                                           STATUS : 201 
                                           HEADERS
                                               Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
                                               Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
                                               Connection=keep-alive
                                               Content-Length=270
                                               Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
                                               Date=Sat, 23 Jan 2016 17:34:01 GMT
                                               ETag="b6aee90833f76c7e670ffb4b24a8a7a5"
                                               QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2016-01-23 19:34:01 UTC
                                               QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                               Server=nginx/1.6.2
                                               Status=201 Created
                                               Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=15768000;
                                               X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
                                               X-Request-Id=e42acfadd6cb14f5b396587c0d837551
                                               X-Runtime=0.035198
                                               X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
                                           BODY
                                               '{"session":{"_id":"56a3b989a0eb471c5a00000f","application_id":xxxx,"created_at":"2016-01-23T17:34:01Z","device_id":0,"nonce":-855163362,"token":"767c6cadc31c5e6c45ba64ef29d45a9b28a2bd0d","ts":1453570447,"updated_at":"2016-01-23T17:34:01Z","user_id":7748679,"id":42627}}'
01-23 23:04:12.127 21733-21757/? D/QBASDK: Connecting to chat..
01-23 23:04:15.127 21733-21757/? D/QBASDK: Connected. Login to chat, currentUser JID: 7748679-xxxxx, resource: 811ee375c6eff567
```

**SDK response when i just close the app and start it again(app is still in task manager)**

```
01-23 23:14:40.617 21733-21733/? D/QBASDK: =========================================================
                                           === REQUEST ==== ed61d1eb-a18d-4ba9-b730-8b552e5e46bc ===
                                           REQUEST
                                               POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
                                           HEADERS
                                               QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                               QB-SDK=Android 2.3.3
                                               QB-Token=767c6cadc31c5e6c45ba64ef29d45a9b28a2bd0d
                                           PARAMETERS
                                               application_id=xxxxx
                                               auth_key=U48ZQsXad2OcBNa
                                               nonce=1359179285
                                               timestamp=1453571080
                                               user[login]=egun1234
                                               user[password]=egun1234
                                               signature=f99dda85c65db5aff212512939fed7408f14461e
                                           INLINE
                                               POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?application_id=xxxxx&auth_key=U48ZQsXad2OcBNa&nonce=1359179285&timestamp=1453571080&user[login]=egun1234&user[password]=egun1234&signature=f99dda85c65db5aff212512939fed7408f14461e
01-23 23:14:48.657 21733-21733/? D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
                                           *** RESPONSE *** ed61d1eb-a18d-4ba9-b730-8b552e5e46bc ***
                                           STATUS : 201 
                                           HEADERS
                                               Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
                                               Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
                                               Connection=keep-alive
                                               Content-Length=270
                                               Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
                                               Date=Sat, 23 Jan 2016 17:44:37 GMT
                                               ETag="778f1e9b028ecb55f5d5aaf210f22c5f"
                                               QB-Token-ExpirationDate=2016-01-23 19:44:37 UTC
                                               QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
                                               Server=nginx/1.6.2
                                               Status=201 Created
                                               Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=15768000;
                                               X-Rack-Cache=invalidate, pass
                                               X-Request-Id=9d23abaa4c411a42bb466a65c9aa78bc
                                               X-Runtime=0.041888
                                               X-UA-Compatible=IE=Edge,chrome=1
                                           BODY
                                               '{"session":{"_id":"56a3bc05a0eb47f007000097","application_id":xxxxx,"created_at":"2016-01-23T17:44:37Z","device_id":0,"nonce":1359179285,"token":"3fdf2abc49d381c5827db4647bade2c51db9b64d","ts":1453571080,"updated_at":"2016-01-23T17:44:37Z","user_id":7748679,"id":42501}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no need to do anything with *session* or login in **onDestroy**
Just making a check in **onResume** of Splash Activity solved my issues.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isChatLoggedIn()) {
            decideLaunchActivity();
            finish();
        }
    }
    private boolean isChatLoggedIn() {
        return QBChatService.isInitialized() && QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this type of coding .

Here you are doing a asynchronous request inside `onDestroy()` . In this case the code inside `onDestroy()` will keep running (untill complete execution of QBUsers.signOut()) even after the complete execution of the `onDestroy()` , since code is running asynchronously . So you need to put this code inside button click and when signOut is success , then exit your app .

Comment: It prints the result only once in the log.  Which i hav mentioned in the code.  I didnt get your point code will keep running.  It succeeds in deleting the session. But i cannot start the app until i kill the app instance from taskmanager. It logins to quickblox and gets stuck after getting the session... Doesnt logs in to chat.

Comment: Obiously It will print the result only once only .

Comment: I didnt get your point - Here I mean that code will keep running untill complete execution of signOut() , when signOut() will finish then excecution of the code will stop , It wont run again and again .

Comment: It succeeds in deleting the session - It will succeeds .

Comment: But in example code in the quickblox documentation.. He has been calling the delete session in onDestory only..

Comment: I have also gone through that documentation , I have seen their Chat Sample also . Personally I feel that their coding structure has many problems . I have modified that coding structure to a working solution . Its working fine for me . So I wont recommend to follow that type of coding structures .

Comment: But i cannot start the app until i kill the app instance from taskmanager - Here I feel that you are getting a problem while doing login again . Here you will be getting an issue  "You have signed already" . Check your logs .

Comment: Ok tell me how to destroy a session..  Please edit your answer with the code part of how exactly u r destroying the session.. PS. My app is fully functional..  I have a splash screen when i create chat instance n log in... If i close the app and dont kill the app from memory..  On next launch it wont move ahead..

Comment: Do you have a logout functionality in your app ?

Comment: No.. No logout functionality to close the app. The logout which i used in code is my attempt to destroy the quickblox session.. U may correct me there..  I m posting my log..  Updating the question

Comment: Keep session alive when you exit the app , When you start the app check that is session alive if alive then dont create session again and do login only . In this case if you got and error (You have logged in already ) while doing login ,then check this error inside onError() and go ahead .

Comment: no. right now stuck with PrivacyList will come back to this later